# tapisrv.exe hangs other processes when terminating from a developed program

Tags: c#, tapi

So I've developed a program in C# in VS2013 that utilizes TAPI to make a phone call on 1 button. Originally I used  the TAPI3 library, but after discovering its not in a working state I switched to JulMar's TAPI 2 wrapper. I'm using Windows 8 64 bit, and although the program is used elsewhere only on Win8 64 bit machines does this issue occur.

Whenever I make a phone call from my program, nothing abnormal happens and the phone call is made. Code runs and everything is OK. But when I close the form where TAPI is used (i.e terminating tapisrv.exe) the service shuts down, and then drags other processes with it every time. This is interfering with drive mappings, cryptography services and other services depending on the PC. The error log in event viewer is below;

> Faulting application name: svchost.exe_TapiSrv, version: 6.3.9600.17415, time stamp: 0x54504177
>
> Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.3.9600.18007, time stamp: 0x55c4c16b
>
> Exception code: 0xc0000008
>
> Fault offset: 0x000000000009311a
>
> Faulting process ID: 0xd4
>
> Faulting application start time: 0x01d0f45613fffb86
>
> Faulting application path: C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe
>
> Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
>
> Report ID: 41b6967a-604a-11e5-829f-f8b156d8c3e7
>
> Faulting package full name:
>
> Faulting package-relative application ID:

I also get an information bubble following it with the following information:

> Fault bucket , type 0
>
> Event Name: APPCRASH
>
> Response: Not available
>
> Cab Id: 0
>
> Problem signature:
>
> P1: svchost.exe_TapiSrv
>
> P2: 6.3.9600.17415
>
> P3: 54504177
>
> P4: ntdll.dll
>
> P5: 6.3.9600.18007
>
> P6: 55c4c16b
>
> P7: c0000008
>
> P8: 000000000009311a
>
> P9:
>
> P10:
>
> Attached files:
>
> C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\Temp\WERE5B1.tmp.appcompat.txt
>
> C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\Temp\WERE5D1.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
>
> C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_svchost.exe_Tapi_881875fa9eb711f34fe5d53182d2b0c47578647_f1915213_cab_053de5df\memory.hdmp
>
> C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_svchost.exe_Tapi_881875fa9eb711f34fe5d53182d2b0c47578647_f1915213_cab_053de5df\triagedump.dmp
>
> These files may be available here:
>
> C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_svchost.exe_Tapi_881875fa9eb711f34fe5d53182d2b0c47578647_f1915213_cab_053de5df
>
> Analysis symbol:
>
> Rechecking for solution: 0
>
> Report ID: 41b6967a-604a-11e5-829f-f8b156d8c3e7
>
> Report Status: 4
>
> Hashed bucket:

Has anybody seen this before? Am I doing something wrong? I know other issues exist regarding TAPI on win8 64 bit but I cant seem to find this specific problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My guess: You have a buggy TSP that crashes your service when the TAPI is uninitialized.

I know no such crashes just from the TAPI. If the crash happens inside the service there is always a TSP involved in such problems.

1. Try to run the TAPI service [isolated in its own service host](http://www.i-b-a-m.de/Andreas_Marschall's_TAPI_and_TSPI_FAQ.htm#_Q:_How_can_6). This will prevent troubles when the service crashes.
2. Open the created DMP files with your VS you received and check what DLL / code causes the crash.

Answer (score 0):

I found running TapiSrv in its own group at least isolates the crash to itself.  Run the following in an elevated command prompt:

sc config Tapisrv type= own